paypal button borders missing in some resolutions
paypal is rendered in id given, as iframe, for some resolution some borders are missing, can any one tell me, how to solve it?
I tried minimizing width of parent element, other ways, still same. I want to pay button should not have missing border at any side in any resolution.
